# is there a way to find out if there is a facebook link in a range of cells in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(Isfacebooklink(A4:437),"LINK","NO LINK")
```

**This doesn't seem to work.**

I also tried to use importXML but doesn't work.
I just want the formula to identify if there is a Facebook link in a range of cells

Comment: It seems you don't clearly understand what functions are in Google Sheets and how they work. We can't just make them up. There is a set list of functions. It's *possible* that a formula could be written to determine if Facebook links exist in a range, but we don't have enough details. We would need to *see those links in the spreadsheet*. I invite you to share a link to the spreadsheet, with permission set to "Anyone with the link."

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A; "facebook")*ISURL(A2:A); "LINK"; "NO LINK"))
```

Comment: ok, so this works: ````=REGEXMATCH((A2),"facebook")````, but this not: ````=REGEXMATCH((A2:A38),"facebook")````. the last one return #VALUE!

Comment: @didi it needs to be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A2:A38,"facebook"))`